# Create multiple pyspark dataframes from csv file

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a csv file which is in below format.

key_string,query

abc,"select * from abc"

pqr,"select * from pqr"

xyz,"select * from xyz"

These tables are in Hive. I want to create dataframes for eg: abc_df,pqr_df and so on.
I can be adding more queries to the csv in future.
How can I create multiple dataframes in pyspark using for loop or any other technique?
I tried following code but its not working:
df is I have read the above csv file

```
x=""
y=[]
for i in df.rdd.collect():
    x= i[0] + "_df"
    x = spark.sql(i[1])
    y.append(x)
print(y)`
```

Pls suggest next steps

Comment: What do you mean by it’s not working? What is your expected outcome, and what did you obtain from your code?

Comment: @mck I just want to create dataframes from the queries available in csv files with key_string_df as dataframe name

Comment: it's a bad idea to have variables as variable names. This is what a dictionary is built for. Do you want a dictionary instead? like {'key_string_df': dataframe, ...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a dictionary for this purpose:

```
y = dict()
for i in df.rdd.collect():
    y[i[0] + "_df"] = spark.sql(i[1])
```

If you want to get the dataframes, you can use, for example,

```
y['abc_df'].show()
```

Comment: Thanks @mck. that helped a lot. 
One more thing
how can I directly access/use abc_df.show() instead of y['abc_df'].show()

Comment: I don't advice using variables as variable names. See my comment in your question. That's why I suggested using dictionary. Is there a problem with using dictionary?